# Why is filename expansion not performed on `*` in `grep --exclude=*.html`?

Tags: bash, wildcards

```
$ echo grep --exclude=*.html -R -i dialect .
grep --exclude=*.html -R -i dialect .
```

Why doesn't bash perform filename expansion  on `*`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there isn't a file matching the glob pattern `--exclude=*.html`

Compare

```
$ echo grep --exclude=*.html -R -i dialect .
grep --exclude=*.html -R -i dialect .
```

but

```
$ touch -- '--exclude=foo.html'
$ echo grep --exclude=*.html -R -i dialect .
grep --exclude=foo.html -R -i dialect .
```

Comment: Thanks. Then how can I prevent unwanted filename expansion after `grep --exclude=`, if I want grep to ignore all html files?

Comment: Quote it, like anywhere else?

Comment: @Tim you can quote it: `--exclude='*.html'`